# jquery datatable ajax appending unwanted query params

Tags: datatables, pagination, server-side, query-string

I am implementing jquery DataTable with server-side pagination. Refer code snippet below -

**Script**

```js
$(async function() {
    $('#registry_table').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: 'localhost:3000/provenance/registries',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
            params: {
                page: 0,
                per_page: 5
            }
        },
        language: {
            searchPlaceholder: "Search...",
            search: "",
            lengthMenu: "_MENU_ &nbsp;items/page"
        }
    });
});
```

**Html**

```html
<table class="table table-striped mg-b-0" id="registry_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left">#</th>
            <th class="text-left">Name</th>
            <th class="text-left">Created on</th>
            <th class="text-left">Transaction</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

But when invokes the REST API it generates incorrect URL

```
http://localhost:3000/provenance/registries?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=3&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=4&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1600077609184
```

As you can see, it's not passing page and per_page query params. And not sure how all other params are getting added to URL.

Answer (score 1):

Changed `params` key to `data` and returned the parameters which I wanted to send with URL as JSON.

Updated Script:

```js
ajax: {
    url: `${self.$provenance.defaults.baseURL}/provenance/registries`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'BWS ' + localStorage.getItem("token")
    },
    data: () => {
        return {page: 0, per_page: 5};
    },
    dataSrc: 'registries'
}
```

It removed all unwanted headers expect `_`

```
http://localhost:3000/provenance/registries?page=0&per_page=5&_=1600082235692
```

Comment: They add the `_` parameter with a timestamp to bypass cache